# C# Linq map one list with another list in the same order

Tags: c#, list, linq

I am very new to LINQ

in Linq below is what I am trying to achieve :

I have two classes -
`List<ClassA>` - `List<ClassB>`

Now I want to map 1st item of Class A to first item of Class b

```
    ClassA.ForEach( a => {
    // how to get the items from ClassB in the same order as it is in CLass b and assign it to Class A
    });
```

Comment: If you just want to simultaneously iterate over two lists of the same length, wouldn't a simple `for` loop do that?  The same indexer can be used on both lists.  Or am I misunderstanding what you're trying to ask?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-7.0)? If you want to enumerate pairs (1st item from listA, 1st item from listB; 2nd item from listA, 2nd item from listB ... nth item from listA, nth item from listB):

```
// a and b are corresponding items from listA and listB
foreach (var (a, b) in listA.Zip(listB, (a, b) => (a, b))) {
  //TODO: relevant code here; a is from listA, b is from listB
}
```

**For instance:**

```
List<int> listA = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3};
List<string> listB = new List<string>() {"A", "B", "C"};
    
foreach (var (a, b) in listA.Zip(listB, (a, b) => (a, b)))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{a} : {b}");
}
```

**Output:**

```
1 : A
2 : B
3 : C
```

Please, [fiddle yourself](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Z9EPzy)

Answer (score 0):

You can `Select` the item along with its index as follows:

```
yourList.Select((x, i) => new {element = v, index = i})
```

Then, you can apply `First` to join them by `index` value:

```
tempList = list2.Select((x, i) => new { somethingElse = x, index = i });
list1.Select((x, i) => new {
    something = x,
    somethingElse => tempList.First((item) => item.index == i) )
});
```

I do not have a .NET env at hand and I did not work in it for a long while, so if there are typos, let me know.